# PHP - Counting XML Nodes with SimpleXML and XPath - Error: Trying to Get Property of Non-Object

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am writing a script to count the matching nodes in my XML feed.

I'm trying to count the applicable 'INTELLCONT' nodes within the parent node ('RECORD') which has the matching username attribute.

I'm getting this error on the last few lines of the code, where I've attempted the count.  It does give a count of zero, on the last line, which is incorrect.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Thank you for any leads.

Here's my code:
PHP:

```
<?php
$secondary_user_id = "jsmith";
$url_bio = "bio_short.xml";
$xml_bio_report= simplexml_load_file($url_bio);

$xml_bio_report->registerXPathNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
$xml_bio_report->registerXPathNamespace('dmu','http://www.dms.com/schema/user-metadata');

$secondary_id_check = $xml_bio_report->xpath('//User[@SecondaryID="'.$secondary_id.'"]');
$user_name = $secondary_id_check[0]['username'];

$url_intellcont = "AI_Intellcont.xml";
$xml_intellcont = simplexml_load_file($url_intellcont);
$xml_intellcont_report = $xml_intellcont;

$xml_intellcont_report->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.dms.com/schema/data');//
$xml_intellcont_report->registerXPathNamespace('dmd','http://www.dms.com/schema/data-metadata');

$xml_intellcont_report_record = $xml_intellcont_report->xpath('//a:Record[@username="'.$user_name.'"]');

//$xml_intellcont_count = count($xml_intellcont_report->xpath('//a:Record[@username="'.$user_name.'"]')->INTELLCONT);
//$xml_intellcont_count = count($xml_intellcont_report_record->INTELLCONT[1]);


//the corrected answer - below, with the array reference.
$xml_intellcont_count = count($xml_intellcont_report_record[0]->INTELLCONT);
echo '<br>$xml_intellcont_count is...'.$xml_intellcont_count.'<br>';
?>
```

The first XML file:
"bio_short.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dmu="http://www.dms.com/schema/user-metadata">
    <User username="john-smith" dmu:userId="14" SecondaryID="jsmith" enabled="false">
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>L</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Email>john-smith@email.com</Email>
        <LocalAuthentication/>
        <Item xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="USERNAME:john-smith"/>
    </User>
    <User username="mary-smith" dmu:userId="19" SecondaryID="msmith">
        <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Email>mary-smith@email.com</Email>
        <LocalAuthentication/>
        <Item xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="USERNAME:mary-smith"/>
    </User>   
</Users>
```

The second XML file:
"AI_Intellcont.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.dms.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.dms.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2018-01-03">
    <Record userId="148" username="john-smith" termId="4" dmd:surveyId="12">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
        <INTELLCONT id="14" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2017-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Sales Tools</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History</CONTYPEOTHER>
            <NEWREV>New</NEWREV>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Comparison of Sales Tools</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="929">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>John</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Smith</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="930">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>S.</FNAME>
                <MNAME>K.</MNAME>
                <LNAME>Smith</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="931">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>K.</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Smith</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="932">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>B.</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Stanwyck</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>      
            <PUBLISHER>Crafts Publishing</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME/>
            <ISSUE/>
            <PAGENUM/>
            <WEB_ADDRESS>https://www.myweb.com/3442</WEB_ADDRESS>
            <EDITORS/>
            <ISBNISSN>17-3 (Electronic) 159-63 (Linking)</ISBNISSN>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <REFEREED/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <IMPACT/>
            <CITATIONS/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2011</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2011-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2011-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
        <INTELLCONT id="15" dmd:originalSource="58TEX" dmd:lastModified="2017-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Sales Tools 2</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History</CONTYPEOTHER>
            <NEWREV>New</NEWREV>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Review of Sales Tools</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="976">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>John</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Smith</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="977">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>S.</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>McQueen</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="978">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>G.</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Cooper</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>Tool Review</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>12</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE>8</ISSUE>
            <PAGENUM>1346-59</PAGENUM>
            <WEB_ADDRESS>https://www.mywebsite.com/479</WEB_ADDRESS>
            <EDITORS/>
            <ISBNISSN>146-80 (Electronic) 10-072 (Linking)</ISBNISSN>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <REFEREED/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <IMPACT/>
            <CITATIONS/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2013</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2013-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2013-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>

    </Record>




    <Record userId="149" username="mary-smith" termId="33" dmd:surveyId="232">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
        <INTELLCONT id="18" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2017-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Sales Tools 34</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History</CONTYPEOTHER>
            <NEWREV>New</NEWREV>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Comparison of Sales Tools</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="959">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>John</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Smith</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="960">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>Mary</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>Smith</LNAME>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>   
            <PUBLISHER>Crafts Publishing 2</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME/>
            <ISSUE/>
            <PAGENUM/>
            <WEB_ADDRESS>https://www.myweb.com/3442</WEB_ADDRESS>
            <EDITORS/>
            <ISBNISSN>17-3 (Electronic) 159-63 (Linking)</ISBNISSN>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <REFEREED/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <IMPACT/>
            <CITATIONS/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2011</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2011-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2011-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>

    </Record>    
</Data>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to get property of a non-object. The `var_dump` is your friend. Trust the errors.

Comment: Trying to debug and I get: `Undefined variable: secondary_id ` where is that set before you reference it?

Comment: The result of SimpleXMLelement::xpath() is an array, an Xpath location path can return a list of nodes. You will need to iterate over it (or access an index).

Comment: Thank you - so, by referencing the '0' element of the array, it does return the correct result.  Please see my edited question for my answer.

Comment: Yes, the secondary_id was a typo.  The array result of SimpleXMLelement::xpath(), being '0', was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array reference to the SimpleXMLelement::xpath() answer would be:

```
$xml_intellcont_count = count($xml_intellcont_report_record[0]->INTELLCONT);
```